# How to detect if a site visitor is browsing the site through Citrix XenApp?

Tags: php, google-chrome, http, citrix, xenapp

Our client has this little LAN with reception terminals where they stream `Chrome` web browser through `Citrix XenApp`. Why? I don't know. And it’s weird, but this tandem seems to spoil the data they submit on our sites forms. Some things that physically can not get cached — get cached somewhere in this `XenApp` thing.

It’s a very important bug for us, because we manage payment processing and it is cashing sensitive cardholder data, which is sooo non PCI DDS compatible!

We’ve told them to install normal Chrome browsers to the end machines, and they say they did. But next day — same issue happens. Then they say — “**oh, it was one of the old machines with `Citrix XenApp` again**.” Meh! Now maybe a week passes and we get same issue again, but they claim that they don’t use `XenApp` anymore, it’s a normal local Chrome.

I don’t believe them. But how can we prove them wrong?

**TL;DR: is it possible to detect if:**

1. A site visitor used normal local Chrome browser or
2. Visited under a Chrome browser streamed through `Citrix XenApp`?

Here’s an example of `USER_AGENT` we're getting:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36

It looks like a totally normal Chrome build. Tried to look through HTTP headers and there is nothing really special there.

Is there a way to determine this, even theoretically?

1. Our application stack is `LAMP`, thus the PHP tag.
2. Please don’t suggest that it’s our software bug. We have hundreds of clients, millions of transactions and this situation happens only with this `Citrix XenApp` crazy client.

EDIT: this is not a duplicate! Here I'm talking about a website running in browser, and server-side scripting. Not about a windows application with APIs and DLLs

Comment: Why not set up a free trial of the XenApp and test it yourself? That might be a good start?

Comment: @DannyThunder, it's a good advice (would be, if I wouldn't have thought about it already), but, unfortunately, not an answer.

Comment: Didnt post as answer, posted as comment. What have you tested? Just checking headers? Maby check how things are cached too?

Comment: Please explain your thought about caching

Comment: Your question is very odd. How do you find out that some data are cached on their side, anyway?

Comment: Because they are sending card data for card present transactions, which was sent a day ago, creating a duplicate charge on customers cards. They swipe new cards, but our system receives old cards data. This is not the question, though. The question is how to detect XenApp

Comment: If I understand what XenApp is correctly, your options are limited, because it is a real Chrome running virtualized on a remote server. The only idea that comes to mind is IP address or JS geolocation.

Comment: Add into HTTP header "CitrixAPP" to WTOS ini.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API for Determining if App is Running on Citrix or Terminal Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186153/api-for-determining-if-app-is-running-on-citrix-or-terminal-services)

Comment: @PaulSweatte: No it is not a duplicate. Here I was talking about a website running in browser, and server-side scripting. Not about a windows application with APIs and DLLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you really can't.. XenApp is, for all intents and purposes, remote desktop. In fact at one point Microsoft RDP and Citrix were the same codebase licensed back and forth.

Longer answer: When you launch Chrome via XenApp, Chrome is actually launched on the server. The display is then captured, redirected, and streamed to the client over ICA. The reason you can't tell with headers or HTTP traffic in general whether or not the user is running XenApp is that from a Chrome<->Webserver perspective (or any application really), nothing really changes. The only delta is in where the UI gets rendered.

One thing I should mention is that if someone's running XenApp in a large-ish install, they probably have some NetScalers kicking around. If so, those can do all kinds of strange HTTP caching, so you may be looking in the wrong place for an explanation of your caching issues..

Comment: Thank you for mentioning NetScaler, I wasn't familiar with this app. Will investigate further, throwing this bone into the fire. One more idea though: if this chrome app is "shared" among several users. Do you think it's cookies are shared, too? It could give me a possibility to throw some individual cookies and if they intersect I could guess they share same Chrome via XenApp. What do you think?

Comment: If it were shared, that would certainly work, but unfortunately it's not.. Every user/stream gets a new instance of the app, in it's own sandbox -- even if you went to the trouble of writing a chrome plugin of some sort, it wouldn't work, you'd just get multiple independent instances that aren't aware of eachother.

Comment: Just some extra info, although it doesn't change the answer (you can't). The question explicitly says "streamed", and XenApp does have a separate streaming feature (however it isn't used very often). If your client is using app streaming then the app is being physically downloaded to the terminal and executed locally in a sandbox. I.e. it doesn't run on the XenApp server.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i am not familiar with Citrix XenApp but taken from here http://www.citrix.com/products/xenapp/how-it-works/application-virtualization.html is the way Citrix XenApp works.

**Understanding application virtualization**
Citrix application virtualization technology isolates applications from the underlying operating system and from other applications to increase compatibility and manageability. As a modern application delivery solution, XenApp virtualizes applications via integrated application streaming and isolation technology. This application virtualization technology enables applications to be streamed from a centralized location into an isolation environment on the target device where they will execute. With XenApp, applications are not installed in the traditional sense. The application files, configuration, and settings are copied to the target device and the application execution at run time is controlled by the application virtualization layer. **When executed, the application run time believes that it is interfacing directly with the operating system when, in fact, it is interfacing with a virtualization environment that proxies all requests to the operating system.**
XenApp is unique in that it is a complete system for virtual application delivery, offering both online and offline application access through a combination of application hosting and application streaming directly to user devices. When users request an application, XenApp determines if their device is compatible and capable of running the application in question. The minimum requirements of a target device are a compatible Windows® operating system and appropriate Citrix client software. If the user device meets minimum requirements, then XenApp initiates application virtualization via application streaming directly into an isolated environment on the user’s device. In the event that the user device is not capable of running a particular application, XenApp initiates session virtualization.

Prevent caching in your htaccess file.

```
Header set Cache-Control "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" env=NO_CACHE
```

In case you want to prevent caching on certain file types try for example:

```
  <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" env=NO_CACHE
    </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: My answer is based on the fact that Citrix XenApp is working as a proxy (of some sort), and from a relative question regarding caching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456726/how-to-disable-proxy-caching-with-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Check for Citrix specific HTTP headers:

- `X-Citrix-Gateway`
- `X-Citrix-Via`

and a proxy header:

- `X-Forwarded-For`

and Citrix specific cookies:

- `WIUser=`
- `WINGDevice=`
- `WINGSession=`
- `WIClientInfo=`

and Citrix specific SSL errors:

- SSL Error 61
- SSL Error 75
- SSL Error 74

**References**

- [Archive: ICA Client Selection and other Web Interface Preferences](http://support.citrix.com/static/oldkc/CTX118859.html)
- [Archive: Access Gateway Enterprise Edition - Set Cookie not Sent to Requesting Host through Clientless VPN](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX120698)
- [XenApp and XenDesktop Authentication (ppt)](http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/25124-102-648712/XenApp%20and%20XenDesktop%20Authentication.ppt)
- [Citrix Client SSL Error Codes](http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx113309)
- [Error: "The server certificate received is not trusted (SSL Error 61)" for Receiver Users](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX101990)
- [How to Extract the SSL Session ID from an HTTP Request and Insert the SSL Session ID into a Custom HTTP Header](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX133524)
- [Case Study: Cookie Does Not Expire for Some Mobile Users](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX126875)
- [How Citrix Application Firewall Modifies Application Data Traffic](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX131488)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect them using their IP address possibly.
If they will use the XenApp their IP will be different than the local lan.

Comment: I am not sure. If the entire LAN has same single API address, then XenApp server within that LAN will have same IP address. We always get same IP address from them, no matter how they connect, its one single hospital building with the only IP address.